# wordpress: wp-graphql not working with custom post type

Tags: wordpress, graphql, wp-graphql

I've created a custom post type that is however not showing up in the GraphiQL explorer.

```
function create_custom_visions_post_type() {
       register_post_type('visions',
                  array(
                      'labels' => array(
                        'name' => __('Visions'),
                        'singular_name' => __('Visions')
                  ),
                    'public' => true,
                    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
                    'show_in_graphql' => true,
                    'graphql_single_name' => 'Vision',
                    'graphql_plural_name' => 'Visions',
));
```

}

According to the wp-graphql docs only the flags "show_in_graphql", 'graphql_single_name' and 'graphql_plural_name' are needed in order to expose a custom post type to the graphql schema.

What am i missing?

Comment: install/activate plugin ;) ... make sure your snippet is called ... "refresh `/graphiql` everrytime schema is changed"

Comment: @xadm yeah the plugin "WP GraphQL" is active and I've restarted gatsby with "gatsby develop".... no success :(

Comment: leave gatsby alone, test wp graphql separately

Comment: @xadm found the solution... had to install gatsby-source-graphql :) thx tho for your help!

Comment: Just restarting Gatsby may not work, sometimes you have to run ```gatsby clean``` if there's a "GraphQL error, e.g. this GraphQL resource should be present but is not," according to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're registering your CPT before the **WPGraphQL** initializes the schema. You can do this by running your CPT registration code in the `graphql_init` hooks like this.

```
function create_custom_visions_post_type() {
       register_post_type('visions',
                  array(
                      'labels' => array(
                        'name' => __('Visions'),
                        'singular_name' => __('Visions')
                  ),
                    'public' => true,
                    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
                    'show_in_graphql' => true,
                    'graphql_single_name' => 'Vision',
                    'graphql_plural_name' => 'Visions',
));
add_action( 'graphql_init', 'create_custom_visions_post_type' );
```

Comment: This answer saved my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

ok stupid me, i forgot to add

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-graphql`,
  options: {
    // This type will contain remote schema Query type
    typeName: `WPGraphQL`,
    // This is field under which it's accessible
    fieldName: `wpgraphql`,
    // Url to query from
    url: `blablabla.local/graphql`,
  },
```

to gatsby-config.js

now my custom post type is available inside wpgraphql{}

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit unrelated, but I found this post while trying to figure out why my Custom Post Type that was registered with the popular plugin "Custom Post Type UI" wasn't appearing in my GraphQL Schema. I was messing with plugin code, and couldn't figure it out until I noticed that in the plugin page for Custom Post Types UI, there is a checkbox to toggle the inclusion of the CPT in GraphQL at the bottom of the edit page for each Custom Post Type in CPTUI. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If your function to create your custom post type looks good, then you might just need to run `gatsby clean` beyond just restarting your project. The Gatsby docs say you might want to run `gatsby clean` when there's a "GraphQL error, e.g. this GraphQL resource should be present but is not".

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/#clean